# Set a progress spinner inside the AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'd like to insert a progress spinner in AutoCompleteTextView while another class performs the autocomplete function. 
I read about the frame Layout ed fixing it in the EditText but the question is: 
How to set the progress spinner? And how to control it?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use this in the layout where you want to display the ProgressBar. You can set the visibility, View.VISIBLE, View.GONE to make it visible and invisible.

```
<ProgressBar
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
```

Comment: And how you control the visibility?  wich events of the adapter/filter you use to show and hide the progress?